# Image creation from memory stream size inconsistency

Tags: c#, .net, image, bitmap

I'm creating an "gif" image from a memory stream. I have 43 bytes memory stream. When I create an image from this stream I get a 70 byte image. What can be the problem? This is the code where I create image:

```
Bitmap httpimage2 = new Bitmap(ms, true);           // ms: 43 bytes memory stream
httpimage2.Save(@"D:\sample.gif", ImageFormat.Gif); // httpimage2: 70 bytes image
```

Comment: memory data size and disk data size is not always 100% the same, is the memory stream already containing binary data as gif? it could also be that the Bitmap.Save method compresses or uses certain specific GIF format not 100% the same as you had initially in the memory stream. Does it work anyway? are you able to open and use the image saved on disk?

Answer (score 1):

I am no expert, that may be because the second image is stored with a larger palette. Are the images identical pixelwise?

Edit: Note also that the framework may encode the image differently than the way the original was created.

Answer (score 0):

they are different formats, so why would they be the same size?

[This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format) gives details about the bmp format, and indicates that the in memory format will not contain the 14-byte Bitmap File Header, which accounts for some of the difference.

[This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Interchange_Format) gives details about the GIF format.

In general some assumptions can be made about the bytes which represent the image when in memory, as you potentially do not need anything in the file to indicate anything about the metadata of  image, as this metadata could be implied in the class which has the bytes as a representation.  for example, a GIF has a fixed length header indicating the format, 87a or 89a.  This may not be necessary in memory as you may have different classes which contain only the bytes which represent the image, one class for images which are 87a and one class for images which are 89a.  Now the image in memory can be smaller as you do not need the information from the file about which format it is as this is only needed when reading hte file and is used to decide which class to instantiate

As the formats are different they will require different amounts information to encode the same image.

You may find that the images are more similar in size if you save the image to disk as a bitmap, but they will probably still be different sizes, and if they are the same size that will just be a coincidence.

Comment: this was more for a comment rather than an answer ;-)

Comment: @DavidePiras I was giving come information whilst then expanding my answer, but on its own , you are right the first line would only really be suitable as a comment

Answer (score 0):

Try to save palette and bitsPerPixel for the image and use them in create